# Массиву указателей не присваиваются новые объекты

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

В приведенном листинге я пытался создать динамический двумерный массив указателей на объекты разных производных классов имеющие общий базовый класс. По умолчанию массив заполнен объектами производного класса EmptyShape. Почему в строчках 48 и 50 объекты класса EmptyShape не заменяются на объекты других производных классов Circle и Rectangle? Как правильно сделать так, чтобы они заменялись?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
  virtual void show() = 0;
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
public:
  void show()
  {
    cout << "circle" << endl;
  }
};

class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
  void show()
  {
    cout << "rectangle" << endl;
  }
};

class EmptyShape: public Shape
{
public:
  void show()
  {
    cout << "empty" << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  int rows = 4, columns = 4;
  Shape **matrix;

  matrix = new Shape* [ rows ];
  for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
    matrix[i] = new EmptyShape [ columns ];

  // Почему объекты класса EmptyShape не заменяется?
  Circle tempObj1;
  matrix[1][1] = tempObj1;
  Rectangle tempObj2;
  matrix[1][2] = tempObj2;


  for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++j )
    {
      matrix[i][j].show();
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас не массив указателей, а массив объектов.

```
  int rows = 4, columns = 4;
  Shape ***matrix;

  matrix = new Shape** [ rows ];
  for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
  {
    matrix[i] = new Shape* [ columns ];
    for ( int j = 0; j < columns; ++j )
      matrix[i][j] = new EmptyShape();
  }

  matrix[1][1] = new Circle();
  matrix[1][2] = new Rectangle();


  for ( int i = 0; i < rows; ++i )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < columns; ++j )
    {
      matrix[i][j]->show();
    }
  }
```